# Twilio: Outbound dail if unanswered will go to voicemail

Tags: java, twilio, twilio-twiml, voicemail

My requirement is I will be making a outbound dial using Twilio client and  verb.
 But if call is unanswered or not reachable it will prompt the caller to send digits (here 1) to go to voicemail and then caller will be able to drop a predefined VM. Can this be achieved using TWiml ? We are using Reactjs and Java. We have tried out AMD but AMD callback is not returning anything when I am calling a number which is unreachable and voicemail service is enabled.

Comment: If you would show some code your question might be better understandable. Have you read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example?

Comment: In the front end we have connected the twilio device and passed fromNumber, toNumber
const device = new Twilio.Device();
device.connect(params);
dialing the toNumber using DIAL verb. But how to go to voicemail
dial = new Dial.Builder().record(Dial.Record
.RECORD_FROM_ANSWER).callerId(fromNumber)
.action(DIAL_CALLBACK_URL)
.method(HttpMethod.POST)..number(toNumber) 
.timeout(30)
.build();
voiceResponse = new VoiceResponse.Builder().dial(dial).build();
    response.setContentType("application/xml");
    response.setStatus(200);
    response.getWriter().print(voiceResponse.toXml());

Answer (score 0):

I spent many long hours for my company this week trying to figure this out. When digging though twilio's documentation you may have come across this piece about [modifying a call in progress](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call-resource#). On the surface, this does not work but I kept digging. My coworker had a thought. Instead of using the call_sid, I used the child call_sid. This was the correct sid and allowed me to redirect the call to the voicemail URL. Hope this gives you an idea to accomplish what you are trying to accomplish.